# Dataform git connection using Google Source Repository

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform, dataform, google-cloud-repository

I am trying to connect a git repository hosted on Google Source Repository with the Dataform environment. The [dataform](https://cloud.google.com/dataform/docs/connect-repository#:%7E:text=Dataform%20service%20account.-,Connect%20a%20Dataform%20repository,go%20to%20the%20Dataform%20page.&text=Select%20the%20repository%20you%20want,click%20Details%20%3E%20Connect%20with%20Git.) documentation states that use of personal access tokens that is accessed by dataform using Secret key.
Since source repository does not support personnel access tokens; What must be the steps to connect the Google Source Repository with the Dataform repository?

I tried to create a new SSH key and added the primary key as a new secret in the GCP environment. The repository gives the following error.
`We are unable to connect to your Git provider with the configured secret. Check that the token is valid and has not expired.`

Comment: Dataform uses https, not ssh, here.

Comment: I tried the https request also but the secret manager is a necessary field. That is why I went to the SSH route.

Comment: https requires a secret: user name and password / token. (Even if the server doesn't want or use it, the software *you're* using insists on having one.) Unfortunately, you apparently can't put in an ssh key.

Answer (score 0):

> Check that the token is valid and has not expired.

That means the secret is interpreted as a token, which is only used for HTTPS URL.
And if your remote URL is an HTTPS one, creating an SSH (private/public) key pair won't be useful.

If you connect to a third-party repository like a GitHub one, you will need a [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token).

To connect to a [G-CSR (Google Cloud Source Repository)](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs), you must first [check your IAM](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/configure-access-control) ([Identity and Access Management](https://cloud.google.com/iam)) in order to make sure you have the right to access/clone the repository.

The [clone documentation](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/cloning-repositories) suggests "Click the SSH authentication tab and follow the instructions to clone your repository."

However, you don't need to register a secret, just to [register your SSH public key on Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/authentication#register_a_public_key).

Comment: The PAT is only an option when it is a third part Git host like GitHub or BitBucket but the authentication in [Google Cloud Source Repository](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/authentication) is through mannual, Cloud CLI and SSH. 
The question is thus what must be done to be able to connect the [G-CSR](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs) git repo with the Dataform repository.

Comment: @angkiratsandhu OK. The documentation you mention was to link a G-CSR Git repo to a thrid-party repository (GitHub, GitLab)

Comment: @angkiratsandhu I have edited the answer with the missing step (SSH public key registration)